# Virtual Host running a server on another port on Webrick

Tags: ruby

This is probably a dump question, but I'm trying to run two Webrick 'servers'. One on port 8080 and one on port 8443. I could start up two servers in 2 threads, but I saw this: https://github.com/ruby/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb#L191 and figured I could run the the one of port 8443 as a virtual host with code something like this:

```
## build default server
svr = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  :Port => 8080,
  :BindAddress => "0.0.0.0"
)
svr.mount_proc("/"){|req, res|
  res.body = "This is default server!"
  res['content-type'] = "text/plain"
}

## Build 'SSL' server
ssl_svr = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  #:DoNotListen => true, # don't forget!
  :Port => 8443,
  :BindAddress => "0.0.0.0",
)

ssl_svr.mount_proc("/"){|req, res|
  res.body = "This is ssl server!"
  res['content-type'] = "text/plain"
}

svr.virtual_host(ssl_svr)
svr.start
```

However, if I do that the server running on port 8443 is never started and never receives requests. This is the output:

```
[2019-10-18 12:07:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.5.0
[2019-10-18 12:07:23] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin18]
[2019-10-18 12:07:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.5.0
[2019-10-18 12:07:23] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin18]
[2019-10-18 12:07:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=94091 port=8080
```

Notice the server on port 8443 is never started.

If I monkey patch Webrick with the following:

```
  def start
    @vhost_threads = []
    @virtual_hosts.each do |vhost|
      puts "Starting vhost"
      @vhost_threads << Thread.new { vhost.start }
    end
    super
  end

  def shutdown
    @virtual_hosts.each do |vhost|
      vhost.shutdown
    end
    @vhost_threads.each {|vt| vt.join }

    super
  end
end
```

Now the server running on port 8443 starts up and can receive requests:

```
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.5.0
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin18]
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.5.0
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin18]
Starting vhost
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=94134 port=8080
[2019-10-18 12:08:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=94134 port=8443
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the first version of the code? Should virtualhosts on Webrick not be used in the manner I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual Hosts in WEBrick are for multiple domain names that are all listening on the same port. Note [this](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/WEBrick.html#module-WEBrick-label-Virtual+Hosts) documentation:

> A server can act as a virtual host for multiple host names. After creating the listening host, additional hosts **that do not listen** can be created and attached as virtual hosts

If you want multiple WEBrick instances listening on multiple ports you can either go multi-process (not what you seem to want) or multi-thread (which you've already done). However, you can probably simplify your life with something like this:

```
require 'webrick'

svr = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  :Port => 8080,
  :BindAddress => "0.0.0.0"
)

ssl_svr = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  :Port => 8443,
  :BindAddress => "0.0.0.0",
)

svr.mount_proc("/"){|req, res|
  res.body = "This is default server!"
  res['content-type'] = "text/plain"
}

ssl_svr.mount_proc("/"){|req, res|
  res.body = "This is ssl server!"
  res['content-type'] = "text/plain"
}

threads = [
  Thread.new { svr.start },
  Thread.new { ssl_svr.start }
].each(&:join)
```

Now your two threads are running and you can reach the WEBrick instances on their respective ports:

```
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin19]
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin19]
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=35295 port=8080
[2019-10-18 11:40:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=35295 port=8443
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I figured, but somehow missed the relevance of "After creating the listening host, additional hosts that do not listen can be created and attached as virtual hosts" Thank you.